# I am getting an undefined offset in php CODE USING A FUNCTION AND SRAND

Tags: php

I get an undefined offset on the list line in the code below.
Any ideas why?
the password is still generated even though I get the offset error

```
function generatePassword($length=6,$level=2){

   list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime(true));
   srand((float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000));  

   $validchars[1] = "23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz";
   $validchars[2] = "23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   $validchars[3] = "23456789_!@#$%&*()-= /abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ_!@#$%&*()-= /";

   $password  = "";
   $counter   = 0;

   while ($counter < $length) {
     $actChar = substr($validchars[$level], rand(0, strlen($validchars[$level])-1), 1);

     // All character must be different
     if (!strstr($password, $actChar)) {
        $password .= $actChar;
        $counter++   ;
   }
   }

   re
```

turn $password;

}

Comment: This isn't real question. Please write more info about your error, what's have you tried, etc., etc.... I flagged this question

Comment: Please read about famous debugging methods in PHP(e.g: printing variables, or using XDebugger - with break points, and etc.), and apply them to your buggy code, before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

[`microtime(true)`](http://php.net/microtime) returns a float value, which never contains a space. Therefore, `explode()` returns an array with only a single item and `list` with two parameters fails as this would require at least two items in the array. Use `microtime(false)` instead:

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime(false));
```

Comment: microtime() = microtime(false) [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: The strange thing is that the function still works, it still generates a random password:

Comment: That's just PHP magic.  It's generating a warning about the missing list item, then assigning it a default value of NULL and continuing regardless of the warning.  That NULL is translated to 0 in the arithmetic that follows, so you are still getting a random password, only a bit "less random" (?) than you are expecting, because one of the inputs is constant when it is supposed to be variable.